# How do I submit a post form to a server page that sends back json to original page

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, cordova

Hello people in the overflow. I am creating a phonegap mobile app. I  have created the api which takes the posted data then displays the json data on screen. How do i get the json data (as a result of the submission) from the screen I submitted to, to the website page I submitted from. I am currently using localhost. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it a few days ago myself thanks guys for your help. The following link shows how to use ajax to post a form. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp After that I just needed to grab the display and use JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) instead of just xmlhttp.responseText as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
formData = {
    paramYourPhpVariable: paramFromForm
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://localhost/test.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //success handler
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

Make sure your web service can request and response JSON format. I attach you a several of links for your clarification.

- http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/25/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-2/
- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I like that you studied my question enough where you found where I first learned how to use an api. May you explain formData = {
    param1: param1
}

Answer (score 0):

In php you could do something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$post = getPost(); // your original post

if($post){          
    echo json_encode(array("Works"=>$post));    //return records back to mobile, or you can return some other data
}else {
    echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"error"));
}

function getPost(){ // decode the json post
    return json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, what does the json_decode do?

Comment: Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.http://uk1.php.net/json_decode

Comment: I dont want my original submitted post i want the page that submitted it to receive the json_encode.

Comment: In my example I'm sending the same data back but you can send whatever data you want  -  echo json_encode($someData);

Comment: I am just getting back this. <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getPost() in C:\wamp\www\unufy\api\index.php on line <i>19</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeee...